# How to make Evolution mail work with my work email address?

Tags: evolution

this is the 1st time to write here and the 1st time to use a mail client other than outlook. I tried to add my enterprise email address to evolution mail, I tried both server types exchange mapi and microsoft exchange. With exchange mapi i get this error message "Authentication failed.
MapiLogonProvider: Failed to login into the server"
With Microsoft Exchange I get this error "Could not connect to server .

Make sure the URL is correct and try again."

Although I'm sure of all the steps
Server: ip address of the mail server
Username: Domainname\Username
Domain: domain name

My system is Ubuntu
Release 11.04 (natty)
Kernel Linux 2.6.38-15-generic
Genome 2.32.1
Evolution 2.32.2

Any kind of help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Quoted:

Out of the box Evolution can only connect to Exchange 2000 and Exchange 2003, this is because it uses OWA to connect, when Exchange 2007 was released, the way OWA was presented changed a great deal. So if you try and connect to a newer version of Exchange it will error. (Before you email in, I know in 2010, its now called Web App not OWA).

But there's nothing to stop you connecting to Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2010 via MAPI, you just have to add a few packages first.

For complete instructions [See this site](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm)

Source: [petenetlive.com](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm)